# How to insert data in many to many relation that has custom fields in typeorm/nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, backend, typeorm

How to save data in many to many relation that has custom fields in `nestjs/typeorm`
Here, I have created relation between cart, customer, and product entity. Relation is as follows:
`Cart and Customer - OneToOne`
`Cart and CartProduct(Junction table for cart and product) OneToMany`
`Product and CartProduct(Junction table for cart and product) OneToMany`

`customer.entity.ts`

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Cart } from './cart.entity';

@Entity()
export class Customer {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Cart, (cart) => cart.customer)
  cart: Cart;
}
```

`cart.entity.ts`

```
import {
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToMany,
  OneToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { CartProduct } from './cartProduct.entity';
import { Customer } from './customer.entity';

@Entity()
export class Cart {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Customer, (customer) => customer.cart)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'customerid' })
  customer: Customer;

  @OneToMany(() => CartProduct, (cartProducts) => cartProducts.cart)
  cartProducts: CartProduct[];
}
```

product.entity.ts

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Brand } from './brand.entity';
import { CartProduct } from './cartProduct.entity';
import { OrderProduct } from './orderProduct.entity';
import { SubCategory } from './subCategory.entity';

@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToMany(() => CartProduct, (cartProduct) => cartProduct.product)
  cartProducts: CartProduct[];
}
```

cartProduct.entity.ts `Junction table for cart and product`

```
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { Cart } from './cart.entity';
import { Product } from './product.entity';

@Entity()
export class CartProduct {
  @Column()
  quantity: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Cart, (cart) => cart.cartProducts, { primary: true })
  cart: Cart;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product, (product) => product.cartProducts, {
    primary: true,
  })
  product: Product;
}
```

Now, while creating cart what I did is,

```
async addProductToCart(
    customerid: number,
    productid: number,
    quantity: number,
  ): Promise<Cart> {
    const customer = await this.customer.findOne({ id: customerid });
    const cart = this.cart.create();
    const product = await this.product.findOne({ id: productid });
    cart.customer = customer;
    const cartProducts = this.cartProducts.create({
      cart,
      product,
      quantity,
    });
    cart.cartProducts = [cartProducts];
    await this.cartProducts.save(cartProducts); //if i add this line then it 
    // says, NOT NULL constraint failed: cart_product.cartid
    return this.cart.save(cart);
  }
```

When I make request to this `addProductToCart` function, then data don't get stored in the database.
So, how to properly insert data using many to many relation with custom field.